# Perform command does not work in Spring Roo

Tags: java, spring, maven, roo

When running the 'perform tests' command in Roo I get the following error:

```
createprocess error=2,the system cannot find the file specified.
```

Now, all the posts on the net suggest that maven should be in PATH. I did that, I rebooted, my maven installation path is in there along with my roo path and java path. I have ROO_HOME set, JAVA_HOME and M2_HOME.

The versions I use are:

- Maven: 3.3.1
- Roo: 1.3.1.RC1
- Java: 1.8.0_45

When I run Maven from the commandline i get this:

```
X:\...>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.3.1 (cab6659f9874fa96462afef40fcf6bc033d58c1c; 2015-03-13T21:10:27+01:00)
Maven home: X:\apache-maven-3.3.1
Java version: 1.8.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: X:\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

Maven seems to be fully functional.

I also can start the roo console from the commandline:

```
X:\...> roo
1.3.1.RC1 [rev 4877cfb]
Welcome to Spring Roo. For assistance press CTRL+SPACE or type "hint" then hit ENTER.
roo> perform tests
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
roo>
```

So my question is, does anybody know if this is a bug? Because I'm under the serious impression that it is. Posts that 'supposedly' solve this problem are 2y or older.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe having "Program Files" (especially the space) causes the issue. Can you try using a "clean" path for JAVA_HOME?

Comment: @Tome I installed the latest into X:\Java\jdk1.8.0_45, same problem. And as I could understand, the creatprocess error comes from the fact that roo cant find the maven executable. But then again, I'm not sure.

Comment: Please run `mvn test` in your project directory & share the (significant) output with us.

Comment: @xerx593 thanks for trying to help. 27 tests run, 27 failures. The main error is 'Failed to load ApplicationContext'. Then ofcourse build failure with error: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) on project ...

Comment: ..ok, then/now we need more details on 'Failed to load ApplicationContext'

Comment: ok but why? The problem is not Maven, it's Roo.

Answer (score 3):

Got the same problem. 
Roo is searching for **mvn.bat** file in the maven's bin directory, but in the version 3.3.1, there is **mvn.cmd** only.

Try either renaming the mvn.cmd to mvn.bat in your maven bin directory (worked for me), or use older version of maven, for example 3.0.4.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I get the chance I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestion! Instead of renaming though, if you use a recent version of Windows (10 in my case) you can create a symlink as well. Open admin command prompt > navigate to your maven bin folder > and execute the command:

```
mklink mvn.bat mvn.cmd
```

> hint: I also do this if I need to swtich between maven versions, pointing my m2_home to a symlink and just switching the symlink when needed to point to the right place.